# How can I open multiple GUI in matlab packaged app

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have created a matlab program that contains multiple GUIs. 
The way a call different GUIs from the main GUI is the following:

```
function button1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

close(main_GUI);
run GUI_1.m;
```

It works fine when the app is not packaged, but it gives me this error when the app is packaged using the matlab packaging application:

```
error using run
GUI_1.m not found
```

It looks like GUI_1.m file does't get included in the package, even when I add it manually from the packaging option.

Is it possible then to have different GUIs in a packaged matlab app? Thank you in advance

Comment: "run executes scripts not currently on the MATLAB path. " This is what the documentation for run says. It seems to me it doesn't make much sense to use 'run' without including script path. Would it work if you simply change "run GUI_1.m" to "GUI_1"?

Comment: I have also tried that without success, keeps on telling me GUI_1 does not exist. Thank you anyway